# Flask: Eve + ACL

Tags: flask, permissions, acl, user-roles, eve

I've implemented simple REST API based on Flask Eve framework.

Now I want to add some custom ACL based on user's roles.
I've investigated this question a little and found interesting solution called Flask-ACL:
https://mikeboers.github.io/Flask-ACL

But there are a few questions I want you to ask:

1. Do somebody know any documentation how to use Flask-ACL + Eve frameworks, because it's not clear enough for me..
2. What is the best way to map list of roles to list of permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Can't help with Flask-ACL (I don't know it) but, have you looked into Eve's own [Role Based Access Control](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#role-based-access-control) yet? It basically allows you total control on what an authenticated user can do.

Comment: I'm interested in permissions-based access control instead of role-based.

Comment: Same problem occurs, and i still have no solution for it !
@smart , Is there any solution you can come up with or help me about it ?